# Changing text color in SELECT boxes

Tags: jquery, html, css

so I've spent the last hour searching, finding many answers here on Stack Overflow and on other sites.  But none of them work.

I want to be able to dynamically set the color of the text in a SELECT drop-down box based on an item that's chosen, using jQuery.

I can change the background color easily:

```
$('#selectBox').css("background-color", "red");
```

But if I do this:

```
$('#selectBox').css("color", "red");
```

It doesn't work.  The text stays black.

Other searching has revealed ::selection but that appears to apply to the style of user-selected text (such as for copy/paste).

Furthermore, I've tried using CSS classes like this:

```
option.red { color: red }
```

And using addClass() to change the class, but again, it no worky.

I've tested this in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You need to change the color of the text in the `<option>` elements.

```
$("#selectBox").find("option").css("color", "red");
```

Comment: Actually, this does change the text color http://jsfiddle.net/LZ22X/ - you have to pulldown the dropdown menu - this is the best you get, the regular text when not pulled down I have not been able to change in Chrome - checking other browsers

Comment: Yes but "*The <select> itself has no text color, only a background color."* is wrong in my opinion.

Comment: @Marcel I was able to change the select's text color in Chrome, Firefox, and IE and removed that statement. At one point this was true, I'm glad this has changed and selects can be styled now - http://jsfiddle.net/73bzd/

Comment: I think I've only tried that before with font-weight which worked as long as I can remember. But nevermind corrected my vote. I'm just confused about why `option.red { color: red }` didn't work for him...

Comment: yea... actually me too now

Answer (score 3):

I've created a fiddle for you. When you select an option from the dropdown, the text color changes dynamically depending on the option's ID.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shMfJ/3/)**

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<select class="selectBox" id="selectBox">
    <option id="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option id="red">Red</option>
    <option id="blue">Blue</option>
</select>



$("select").change(function () {
    var ID = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
    $('#selectBox').css('color', ID);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing nothing wrong, this behavior is a limitation of  the SELECT element. There is very little you can do with it via CSS.

I suggest looking into custom dropdown controls (there're several pretty good jQuery ones)

Answer (score 0):

I think the CSS changes with select tag would be conflict with other browser, specially with internet explorer.

If you have such a specific requirement then try this jQuery function to get perfect result.

http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/